# Uncaught ReferenceError: getLocation is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a website and now stuck with an error. I want to get my current latitude and longitude when my page is loaded. But the function with that code is not running when the page is loaded and it shows an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: getLocation is not defined".

This is my HTML part

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">   
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=(mykey)&callback=initialize">
</script>
<style>
  #map {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;    
</style>
</head>
 <body>
 <div id="map"><img src="adminpanel/images/loader.gif" width="3%" height="5%"/>&nbsp;<b>Loading Map</b></div>  
 </body>
</html>
```

This is java script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  getLocation();
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  function getLocation() {
     if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
     } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
     }
  }
  function showPosition(position) {
     window.location.href="search-product.php?Lat=" + position.coords.latitude + "&Lng=" + position.coords.longitude;
   }

var map;
var Markers = {};
var infowindow;
var locations = [
<?php for($i=0;$i<sizeof($locations);$i++) { $j=$i +1; ?>
[
  'hi ',
  '<a href="map_location_check.php?shop_id=<?php echo $locations[$i]['shop_id']; ?>" title="Click Here"><?php echo $locations[$i]['shop_name'].'<br>'.$locations[$i]['shop_address']; ?></a>',
  <?php echo $locations[$i]['map_latitude']; ?>,
  <?php echo $locations[$i]['map_longitude']; ?>,
  0
] <?php if($j!=sizeof($locations)) echo ",";  } ?>
];

var origin = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[0][2],locations[0][3]);
function initialize () {
 var mapOptions = {
  zoom:12,
  center:origin
 };
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),mapOptions);
 infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
 for(i=0;i<locations.length;i++) {
  var position = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][2], locations[i][3]);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position:position,
    map:map,
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i){
  return function() {
    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][1]);
    infowindow.setOptions({maxWidth: 200});
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  }
}) (marker, i));
Markers[locations[i][4]] = marker;
}
locate(0);
}

function locate(marker_id){
 var myMarker = Markers[marker_id];
 var markerPosition = myMarker.getPosition();
 map.setCenter(markerPosition);
 google.maps.event.trigger(myMarker, 'click');
} 
</script>
```

Thanks for your help..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine. This means you have another call to the function somewhere else and the file isn't loading ,in which, case you need to wait until the file loads

```
window.onload = function(){getLocation()}
jQuery(window).on('load', getLocation);
```

see https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GdNLVL

Also, on window.location.href in here.

```
  function showPosition(position) {
     window.location.href="search-product.php?Lat=" + position.coords.latitude + "&Lng=" + position.coords.longitude;
   }
```

You would probably want.

```
  function showPosition(position) {
    return window.location.href+"search-product.php?Lat=" + position.coords.latitude + "&Lng=" + position.coords.longitude;
   }
```

**EDIT 2:**  **Correcting** You need to create your instance onload

```
window.onload = function(){var origin = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[0][2],locations[0][3]);};
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `getLocation` after you defined it or assign it to a variable to be hoisted `var getLocation = function(){...}`

Comment: Thanks .. But now it shows another error as "Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined"